# Lie derivative and variation

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-fields, variational-calculus

I have a couple of questions regarding the variation in Noether's theorem

1. Given an arbitrary tensor field $\phi$ can we generally identify an infinitesimal variation with the Lie derivative of that field along some vector field (like it's done in GR where the metric is varied w.r.t a Killing vector field to give a symmetry)? $$ {\delta} \phi = {\mathcal L}_\xi\phi$$
2. In many proofs of [Noether's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether%27s_theorem#Field-theoretic_derivation), the commutativity of $\delta$ and $\partial$ is implied in order to use integration by parts later. This is certainly the case for scalar fields, but it seems to fail for tensor fields (since $\nabla$ and $\mathcal L$ don't commute in general). What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your first question is no, not all field variations are given by coordinate transformations. For example, if you have a complex scalar field, then performing a $U(1)$ transformation (multiplying by a phase) is certainly not a coordinate transformation.

For your second point, I'm not sure I see the question as both the statements you've made are, as far as I'm aware, correct.

Comment: So if we have any arbitrary transformation of the field we can turn it into a variation by encoding it in the components of the prolonged vector field defined on the jet space?

Comment: @Tonetta778 essentially, yes. Though if you're sufficiently familiar with diff. geo. to think about jet spaces, you might find [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/1801.07064) and [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/1906.08616) useful. The latter in particular I found enlightening with regards to Noether's theorem.

Comment: thanks a lot. Just to make sure i understood this, the variation in the transformation u mentioned comes out to be $$\delta \phi = i\xi\phi$$, and in general for some arbitrary transformation we have to "crunch the derivative"

Comment: For a $U(1)$ gauge transformation with gauge parameter $\xi$, that would indeed be the correct derivative. All of this is finding generators of Lie groups, so the general procedure for a finite transformation $T_\alpha$ with parameter $\alpha$ is to compute $\frac{\partial}{\partial \alpha}T_\alpha[\phi]\Big|_{\alpha=0}$.